# FIle upload in GCP API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-gateway

I'm trying to create the following `api config` for **GCP API Gateway** (ommitted real backend URL):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: upload
  description: upload
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
security:
  - api_key: [ ]

paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      summary: uploads a file.
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      operationId: uploadFile
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: file
          description: The file to upload.
          required: true
          type: file
      responses:
        '200':
          description: upload successful
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://XXXXX.XXXXX
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS    

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

Running gcloud (replaced real variables with placeholders)

`gcloud api-gateway api-configs create uploadconfig --api=[API] --openapi-spec=openapi.yaml --project=[MYPROJECT] --backend-auth-service-account=[ACCOUNT]`

This results in this **error message**:

> ERROR: (gcloud.api-gateway.api-configs.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
> 'location: "unknown location"
> kind: ERROR
> message: "http: repeated message field 'google.protobuf.Struct.fields' referred to by message 'UploadFileRequest' cannot be mapped as an HTTP parameter."
> location: "unknown location"
> kind: ERROR
> message: "http: cyclic message field 'google.protobuf.Struct.FieldsEntry.value' referred to by message 'UploadFileRequest' in method 'method 1.xxxxxxx.UploadFile' cannot be mapped as an HTTP parameter."

I verified the gcloud command with a different api configurations and backends.

The config itself seems fine, i.e. it validates with Swagger editor, still gcloud won't accept it.
How do I define a file upload via API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [file upload](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#file_upload) Endpoints does not accept the `type: file` for file upload parameters, `type: string` should be used instead.And I tried config with changed parameters and it validates with Swagger editor results are [here](https://ibb.co/3rZL0H2).

Comment: I'm already using gcloud.  I updated the post. I replaced the real backend URL with a placeholder. Gcloud command just runs fine with a different configs. As of now I have serveral APIs working. I seems some kind of bug with binary upload.

Comment: I have updated my answer, feel free to check it.

Answer (score 0):

With SwaggerHub and OpenAPI 2 spec, this is how I got this file upload to work. Let me know if you have any questions. This is written in YAML as opposed to JSON spec. It took some reading and some experimentation, but here's the Gcloud documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects
And the SwaggerHub info as well: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/

```html
  /upload/storage/v1/b/{bucket}/o?uploadType=media&name={objectName}:
    post:
      summary: Upload an object directly to a bucket
      description: Upload an object directly to a bucket
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: Authorization
          type: string
          required: true
        - in: path
          name: bucket
          required: true
          type: string
          description: The name of the bucket to upload to.
        - in: path
          name: objectName
          required: true
          type: string
          description: The name the object will receive in the bucket.
        - in: header
          name: Content-Type
          type: string
          required: true
          description: The content type of the upload. Ex. text/plain
        - in: formData
          name: fileToUpload
          type: file
          description: The file to upload.
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
        204:
          description: Success - No Content
        400:
          description: Bad Request
        401:
          description: Insufficient Privileges
        404:
          description: Not Found
```

It DOES accept type: file in the formData request.